# TikZ/PGF \closedcycle to y axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot [domain=0.7:1.6,samples=20, fill=red!50!white] 
            {(1.5*x - 4.5)^2/(10*x) + 1} \closedcycle ;
        \addplot [domain=0.7:1.6,samples=20, blue, very thick] 
            {(1.5*x - 4.5)^2/(10*x) + 1} 
            node[at start, above, black] {$(x1,y1)$} 
            node[at end, above, black]   {$(x2,y2)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produce this

[image]

What I want is to

1. Fill the area between the blue curve and the x-axis (red fill)
2. Fill the area between the blue curve and the y-axis, that is, indicating the region interval y2 to y1 on the y-axis.

I was hoping there is some way to specify `\closedcycle` with respect to the y-axis or similar.

A solution could of course be to calculate the points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`, but it feels very un-`TikZ`y.

(This means that there will be a white rectangle defined by the origin, (x1,0), (x1,y2) and (0,y2))

Comment: You can draw a second function.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Would this be OK : `{(1.5*x - 4.5)^2/(10*x) + 1} |- (axis description cs:0,0) |- (current plot begin) ;` instead of `\closedcycle` ?

Comment: I mean `\addplot [domain=0:0.7,samples=2, fill=red!20] 
            {(1.5*0.7 - 4.5)^2/(10*0.7) + 1} \closedcycle ;`

Comment: Neither works. I'll update the question in a bit.

Comment: This is a completely different question don't you think?

Comment: It could be interpreted in different ways, I agree. I apologize for not being sufficiently concise with my original formulation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define a new command `\closedcycley` that does the same as the normal `\closedcycle`, but for the y axis. If you then plot the function twice, once with `\closedcycle` and once with `\closedcycley`, both times slightly transparently, you'll get the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\def\closedcycley{%
    -| (perpendicular cs: 
        horizontal line through={(current plot begin)}, 
        vertical line through={(\pgfplots@ZERO@x,\pgfplots@ZERO@y)})
    -- cycle
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis on top]
        \addplot [opacity=0.5,domain=0.7:1.6,samples=20, fill=red!50!white, draw=none] 
            {(1.5*x - 4.5)^2/(10*x) + 1} \closedcycle ;
        \addplot [opacity=0.5, domain=0.7:1.6,samples=20, fill=red!50!white, draw=none] 
            {(1.5*x - 4.5)^2/(10*x) + 1} \closedcycley ;
        \addplot [domain=0.7:1.6,samples=20, blue, very thick] 
            {(1.5*x - 4.5)^2/(10*x) + 1} 
            node[at start, above, black] {$(x1,y1)$} 
            node[at end, above, black]   {$(x2,y2)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```