# changing reference line of `\closedcycle`" and "`fill`" option in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween, matlab2tikz

I have used Matlab2tikz package to obtain tikz files of some plots drawn by Matlab. They have a problem in showing colored confidence intervals using "`fill`" option. My conjecture is that the problem stems from the fact that reference line for "`\closedcycle`" and "`fill`" option is y=0 (or x axis) that is using them the area between the curve and y=0 (or x axis) will be colored, Thus when the curve crosses the x axis colored confidence intervals will not be acceptable.

Considering the notable numbers of plots generated by Matlab2tikz, It is important to solve the problem by making minimum changes in the codes. I think this change can be shifting reference line to y=ymin. I think I should define a new command let say `\closedcycleymin` similar to `\closedcycley` in this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113711/tikz-pgf-closedcycle-to-y-axis).

Would you mind helping me find the solution?

Bests

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=1.245in,
height=0.895in,
at={(0.758in,1.792in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=20,
ymin=-0.00272712850308932,
ymax=0.000803621131163322,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={ph}
]
\addplot[fill=white!90!black, draw=black, forget plot] table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1   -0.000821339838121972\\
    2   -0.00164043467432739\\
    3   -0.000895855599007665\\
    4   -0.000315424225262793\\
    5   0.000146513747520635\\
    6   0.000490017617162638\\
    7   0.000687017984049317\\
    8   0.000783609682610873\\
    9   0.000803621131163322\\
    10  0.00073111890779905\\
    11  0.00064470236661438\\
    12  0.000533672630962923\\
    13  0.000438218545990327\\
    14  0.000349701399270754\\
    15  0.000244212703270491\\
    16  0.00016698621322208\\
    17  0.000119605897750126\\
    18  7.82908188883209e-05\\
    19  5.34333417323973e-05\\
    20  4.07765839765695e-05\\
}
\closedcycle;
\addplot[fill=white, draw=black, forget plot] table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1   -0.00140736744545601\\
    2   -0.00272712850308932\\
    3   -0.00192479768024259\\
    4   -0.00131335464603441\\
    5   -0.000783836032350087\\
    6   -0.000318439289539476\\
    7   3.60206971690225e-05\\
    8   0.000282621786338977\\
    9   0.000410640041633922\\
    10  0.000406665195391912\\
    11  0.000341989605677194\\
    12  0.000231338661868178\\
    13  0.000148732813468034\\
    14  8.29434473632843e-05\\
    15  8.70901360309242e-06\\
    16  -2.16298098251486e-05\\
    17  -3.09431658059387e-05\\
    18  -3.62579623929987e-05\\
    19  -3.49849226862417e-05\\
    20  -2.9692048179123e-05\\
}
\closedcycle;
\addplot [color=black, line width=3.0pt, forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1   -0.00112518900664359\\
    2   -0.00213651644225243\\
    3   -0.00138090837487913\\
    4   -0.000826424694277475\\
    5   -0.000332414099773573\\
    6   9.50139834939742e-05\\
    7   0.000381511379481362\\
    8   0.000536434127747512\\
    9   0.000585284480227507\\
    10  0.000557350139363697\\
    11  0.000483026729034827\\
    12  0.000387974647548721\\
    13  0.000291042096495643\\
    14  0.000204281289809255\\
    15  0.000133847420764794\\
    16  8.1421682770134e-05\\
    17  4.57275008939389e-05\\
    18  2.38646695963638e-05\\
    19  1.23435421254728e-05\\
    20  7.79003027335727e-06\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but this is what I realized. Based on this comment [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113711/tikz-pgf-closedcycle-to-y-axis#comment250780_113711), you just need to put the following command in the preamble.

```
\newcommand{\myclosedcycle}{|- (axis description cs:0,0) |- (current plot begin)}
```

And now use `\myclosedcycle` instead of `\closedcycle`. Here is the output after the execution:
[image]

```
% Qaher Marufiazar
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\myclosedcycle}{|- (axis description cs:0,0) |- (current plot begin)}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=1.245in,
height=0.895in,
at={(0.758in,1.792in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=20,
ymin=-0.00272712850308932,
ymax=0.000803621131163322,
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={ph}
]
\addplot[fill=white!90!black, draw=black, forget plot] table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1   -0.000821339838121972\\
    2   -0.00164043467432739\\
    3   -0.000895855599007665\\
    4   -0.000315424225262793\\
    5   0.000146513747520635\\
    6   0.000490017617162638\\
    7   0.000687017984049317\\
    8   0.000783609682610873\\
    9   0.000803621131163322\\
    10  0.00073111890779905\\
    11  0.00064470236661438\\
    12  0.000533672630962923\\
    13  0.000438218545990327\\
    14  0.000349701399270754\\
    15  0.000244212703270491\\
    16  0.00016698621322208\\
    17  0.000119605897750126\\
    18  7.82908188883209e-05\\
    19  5.34333417323973e-05\\
    20  4.07765839765695e-05\\
}
\myclosedcycle ;
\addplot[fill=white, draw=black, forget plot] table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1   -0.00140736744545601\\
    2   -0.00272712850308932\\
    3   -0.00192479768024259\\
    4   -0.00131335464603441\\
    5   -0.000783836032350087\\
    6   -0.000318439289539476\\
    7   3.60206971690225e-05\\
    8   0.000282621786338977\\
    9   0.000410640041633922\\
    10  0.000406665195391912\\
    11  0.000341989605677194\\
    12  0.000231338661868178\\
    13  0.000148732813468034\\
    14  8.29434473632843e-05\\
    15  8.70901360309242e-06\\
    16  -2.16298098251486e-05\\
    17  -3.09431658059387e-05\\
    18  -3.62579623929987e-05\\
    19  -3.49849226862417e-05\\
    20  -2.9692048179123e-05\\
} \myclosedcycle ;
\addplot [color=black, line width=3.0pt, forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1   -0.00112518900664359\\
    2   -0.00213651644225243\\
    3   -0.00138090837487913\\
    4   -0.000826424694277475\\
    5   -0.000332414099773573\\
    6   9.50139834939742e-05\\
    7   0.000381511379481362\\
    8   0.000536434127747512\\
    9   0.000585284480227507\\
    10  0.000557350139363697\\
    11  0.000483026729034827\\
    12  0.000387974647548721\\
    13  0.000291042096495643\\
    14  0.000204281289809255\\
    15  0.000133847420764794\\
    16  8.1421682770134e-05\\
    17  4.57275008939389e-05\\
    18  2.38646695963638e-05\\
    19  1.23435421254728e-05\\
    20  7.79003027335727e-06\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```